# What's the meaning of these '$show' relations?

Tags: alloy

With the simple model below some instances contain relations marked as '$show_upd'. It seems they're created when the 'some' qualifier is used in 'f1'. What do they represent?[image]

```
sig Licence {}

sig UpdateRow { 
    next: lone UpdateRow, 
    licence: one Licence
}

sig UpdateChain { 
    first: one UpdateRow 
}

fact f1 {
    // every licence belongs to one or more updateRows
    all lic: Licence | some upd: UpdateRow | upd.licence = lic
}

pred show {} 
run show
```

Comment: It depicts the upd satisfying your fact. If you want to get rid of it, just replace the content of your fact by :     all lic: Licence | some lic.~licence

Comment: Loïc Gammaitoni, thanks for your answer. I'm still not sure why it is shown as there's no relation specified from Licence to UpdateRow. It's interesting that even bigger instances contain only one such linkage - is the model (implicitly) constrained in that sense?

Comment: Normally when you run a predicate, alloy try to highlight on the instance how the predicate holds. e.g. if you run a predicate with an argument typed by a signature S, then one of the S-atoms satisfying the predicate will be highlighted. My thoughts is that something similar happen. You have an empty predicate so they take one of the concept you have declared in a fact, and highlight it in the instance. Not sure why though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy Analyzer names Skolem constants with a dollar sign as a prefix. More specifically, Skolem constants (or witnesses to the Skolemized constraints) are identified with the predicate that you are checking (in this case the predicate *show*), together with the quantifier that is related to the given Skolem constant (in this case *some upd: UpdateRow*), prefixed with the dollar sign $.

Skolemization, as well how are witnesses of Skolemized constraints depicted in Alloy Analyzer, is briefly covered in the [Alloy quick guide](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/skolem.html) and in more details in *5.2.2  Skolemization* in the Software Abstractions book.